# How to start and debug a console line application from an XNA game project

Tags: c#, debugging, xna

I have 3 projects on my solution. Two console line applications and one XNA game project (and a content project for XNA). When I use the following code to call one console app from another:

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"..\..\..\..\..\ChildProcess\bin\Debug\ChildProcess.exe",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    };

    Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
```

I can put a break point in ChildProcess app and debug it. However if I copy this code to XNA game project (at the beginning of its Main method) and set it to be the starting project the ChildProcess app is being started but the break point in ChildProcess app never gets hit. I tried changing ProcessStartInfo init properties but it didn't help.

How can I debug console app when its being called this way? My XNA game runs in windowed mode.

Answer (score 0):

you could start your childprocess in suspended state, and manually attach a debugger ...

unfortunately .net seems to be unable to do that directly ... however you could use pinvoke to call winapi CreateProcess() with the CREATE_SUSPENDED flag...

ugly, but it should work ...